# @media screen and (max-width:768px) not working

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a new website for my uni assignment but my 
    @media screen and (max-width:720px) 
    does not have any changes when I typed in the code as provided as below. What I am trying to do is that I want to make my navigation-links to hide under a burger to be display in mobile (will include javascript once this is working)

I had tried with

```
@media screen and (max-width:1280px){
#topnav {
  width:100%;
  background:#000000;
}
#brand {
    width:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#brand h1 {
    display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

#search,form,button{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 44px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.srch_bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 42%;
}
.clr-btn {
    color:#636c72;
}
#link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
}
#link a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
}
.szp {
    color: #F07330;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.szr {
    color: #F20000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.szs {
    color: #063780;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.szu {
    color: #1E7305;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

and also with

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    #topnav {
    width:100%;
    background:#000000;
}
#brand {
    width:17%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#brand h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

#search,form,button{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 44px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.srch_bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 330%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 42%;
}
.clr-btn {
    color:#636c72;
}
#link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 53%;
    margin: 0;
}
#link a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px;
    color: #fff;
}
.szp {
    color: #F07330;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.szr {
    color: #F20000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.szs {
    color: #063780;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.szu {
    color: #1E7305;
    font-size: 24px;
}
}
```

both worked but when come to

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){

}
```

it doesn't seem to be working btw I also have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

linked in html otherwise my @media 1024px and 1280px won't work

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px){
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #links{
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top:8vh;
        background-color: #000000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .burger {
     display:block;
    }
}
```

I want it to display none on the page first so I know it work properly

btw this is my html

```
<html>

 <head>
   <title>Solexton</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="icon" href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\picas\s.png" type="image/png">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\wdt\asg\css\style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topnav">
    <div id="brand">
      <h1 class="logo"><i class="fab fa-stripe-s"></i>olexton</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
      <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input class="srch_bar" type="text" name="search_key" 
         placeholder="Looking for..."/>
      </form>
        <button class="srch-btn" name="submit"><i class="fas fa-search clr- 
         btn"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="link">
      <a href="promo.html"><i class="fas fa-percent szp"></i> Promotions</a>
      <a href="room.html"><i class="fas fa-bed szr"></i>  Rooms</a>
      <a href="booking.html"><i class="far fa-bookmark szs"></i> Saved</a>
      <a href="signin.php"><i class="far fa-user-circle szu"></i> Sign 
       In</a>
    </div>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your complete code, what you have tried so far ? In JSfiddle, codepen or similar. So we can analyse and help you out.

Comment: What exactly is not working, because I have tested your code and it's behaving as expected...

Comment: @ScottieG So is there a solution to my problem ?? And what causing it exactly ??

Comment: @Adam__See - Your code works for me. What is the issue you are experiencing?  You have stated that "@media 720px is not working" but your question title is "@media screen and (max-width:768px) not working"  - So which IS IT?

Comment: @Adam__See one of your fundamental issues is that you are claiming something is not working and asking for solutions without adequately describing the problem. We can only know what you actually state - we can't see what arcadia you are trying to reach, and we can't read your mind's eye ... so please try and avoid *subjective* descriptions, such as "it's not doing what I want" -- that's meaningless ; if something "is not working" please state 1) How it should look to be described as working and 2) how it looks at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottieG Sorry, erm the question is that when I "@media screen and (max-width:768px){}" it not showing any changes even though I typed in some code as provided above.  I'm trying to make the navigation links to hide in a burger for mobile screen

Comment: @Adam__See - You haven't added any code under `@media screen and (max-width:768px){}` so nothing is going to happen at that break-point.

Comment: @ScottieG No I did have code under "@media screen and (max-width:768px){}" but no changes, anyway I still solve the problem. ( I just place the "@media screen and (max-width:768px){}" above "@media screen and (max-width:768px){}" did not know the actual reason of this cause but it work fine anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should write media queries from small screens to large screens. Becouse last line css code overwrites to over previous css lines.
For example from bootstrap;

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: This is not the case with Media Queries as they target the browser size and apply the styles specified within the Media Query. However it IS a best practice to do it this way.

Comment: So should I change my css Media Queries to ascending order / descending order ?

Comment: @Adam__See You don't have to as it won't make a difference with Media Queries, but it is generally considered good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some other media query that interfere in small screen size, you can use your browser Inspector, scale you screen size under 720px, select you body from the source (elements tab) and in the right sidebar check where the display property is set.

Maybe in other CSS the same element is targeted and the display property is set.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, your media queries are working, you just can't tell because there is no content.

The browser will display the default which is a white background unless you have specified otherwise, which based on the code supplied, there is nothing to show once the browser resizes above `720px`.

Add some content to the body and try resizing the browser to the relative break-points, or perhaps try adding the below to visibly see the change.

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  body {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have some content already it just that I'm using 

    body {
        display:none;
    }

to make it so I know that is linked 

btw still cant work

Comment: Can you add that content to the question please?  It makes a difference.